# Calculate days between current day and another day

Tags: php, html, date, datediff

I want to calculate days between 'today' and a given date, `$m->status_date`.

In the code below, the first part with `text1` and `text2` works well, but the second part with `text3` and `text4` doesn't work.

How should I change my code? Here is how I have my code currently:

```
   <?=($m->status_date!='0000-00-00' 
    ? "text1 ".$m->st_cnt.
    :"text2")
?>
<?=(strtotime('now')-strtotime($m->status_date)>=120 
&& $m->status_date!='0000-00-00' 
    ? "text3":"text4")
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
```